# Unable to run app in Simulator 9.0 using XCode 7.0

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I run my application using XCode 7.0. Everytime I am getting below error. How to fix this issue.[image: Simulatore Error]

I am using Mac with 10.10.5 . I searched that 10.10.4 later supports XCode 7.0

Please suggest where I went wrong...!

Comment: YES..Same error occurs with XCode 7.0 but XCode 6.4 works fine.

Comment: I guess, you should update your svn. Currently, Xcode 7.2.1 is a stable version. Here's the update [link](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/xcode/id497799835?ls=1&mt=12).

Comment: I have checked with XCode 7.2 also. It is getting same error.I unable to run app in simulator.

Comment: Seems the answer is given to you in the alert view no, install the simulator...

Answer (score 0):

Go to Xcode -> Preferences- Downloads tab. 
Here you will be able to see list of simulator available for downloading. 
Download the required simulator. 
Restart Xcode
You will be able to run your project on simulator without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so it seems like the run time components for the simulator are not installed with your version of Xcode (this may have happened when updating or downloading a beta and Xcode got confused).

Try do the Following: *Xcode > Preferences > Downloads > Check and Install Now*

[image: Press Xcode]

[image: The Preferences]

[image: You'll see something like this]

[image: Go to Downloads and press Check and install now]

That should Help, otherwise you can go to itunesconnect or anywhere on the web and download and add the simulator files manually.